# Get OAuth2 authorize code with no user interaction but by passing username and password through parameters

Tags: oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory

I am new to azure and trying to retrieve authorization code after hitting the below API without UI interaction.

[image]

I don't want to interact with the Microsoft sign-in page. Is there any way to resolve this issue?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Authorization code can be retrieved using OAuth 2.0 authorization code grant flow which require User Interaction .

This flow is mainly used for single page applications, web applications and native application where user interaction is required to get the access token.

The authorization code is a temporary code that the client will exchange for an access token and can be generated in the the address bar along with reply URL after user's sign in.

Refer https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow

If you looking to get access token for the service application where no user interaction is required, then [client-credential flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow) can be used to get the access token which can be used further to call Microsoft Graph API or any customized product API.